# I'm running kernel version A, but want to install drivers onto kernel version B. Is this possible?

Tags: drivers, wireless, kernel

When the new version of the kernel (version 4.4.0-72) installed, it didn't install the driver for the wireless card. As a result, when I boot into the new kernel, I can't get online. (I don't have access to a wired connexion, and won't in the near future.)

I can't install the driver with *apt*, as that would require an internet connexion.

I'm typing this having booted into the old version of the kernel (4.4.0-65), which has the wireless driver. Is there something I can do from here that'll install the driver over there?

Comment: You'll need to obtain the .deb file that contained the original driver and then just reinstall it when the newer kernel is running. If you didn't save it, you'll have to download it again.

Comment: Please tell us about the wireless device in question. Is it PCI or USB? If PCI, please post: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` If USB, please post: `lsusb`